# capture any form from javascript in JOOMLA

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

currently I am developing JOOMLA extension. In that extension what I need is to capture any form from loaded page in the bowser by giving name or ID of it and route its data to any submission page i wanted.

So what I am anticipating is that I should write a JAVA SCRIPT and this script should be loaded every time with every page. And this script will take care of routing data from any form with a given ID to my desired sever side URI.

Now my question is how to write such script that automatically install itself when extension is installed and load itself not only with extension pages but also with every other page. other way around a global JAVASCRIPT file with extension.

Comment: my extension uses forms. So i want generic way to capture forms from any other extension like breezing form or content builder etc  otherwise i will be bound to write separate and dedicated codes for different types of form extensions to capture their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system plugin will be loaded on every request. So I suggest to write one and implent the onafterroute function to add the script to the document. Don't forget to check if the document is an html one. There is also an event which will be loaded when a form is created.